# A Process is refusing to die

Tags: c#, kill

Based on [other questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237628/c-process-killing), I'm using `System.Diagnostics.Process` to `Start` and `Kill` a process:

```
this.childProcess.Kill();
this.childProcess.WaitForExit();
this.childProcess.Close();
```

I would assume that `WaitForExit` deals with the asynchronous nature of the `Kill` command, however the process in question (perl.exe) refuses to die.  Instead it lingers for some period of time.

This "period of time" is causing a race condition.  Is there anyway I can make sure this process actually dies?

Comment: This is an XY question.  Y is "why can't I kill the process".  X is "why did I write code to kill the process in the first place".  I have to recommend pursuing X.

Comment: @Hans I think knowing why a process isn't dying is a useful step in analyzing the data flow in my project.  I could rewrite large sections of my project on the assumption that the process can't be killed only to reintroduce the same problem.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure what you mean by "make sure this process actually dies."  Under the hood the `Kill` method eventually calls [TerminateProcess](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms686714(VS.85).aspx) which is the most effective way to kill a process and `WaitForExit` won't return until the process is actually gone.

The `Kill` method can fail to actually kill the process in at least 2 circumstances

1. You don't have sufficient rights to kill the process
2. There is a debugger attached to the process (I believe this prevents TerminateProcess from working).
3. Uninterruptable I/O operation (thanks Daniel)

Do either of these apply to your scenario?

Comment: I believe I has sufficient rights since: a) I spawned it, b) it does "sometimes" die.  I experience the problem if I have the debugger running on the Parent process, or if I don't us the debugger at all.

Comment: There's another case where a process isn't able to die (at least, not for a while): if it's doing an uninterruptible I/O operation.  It's highly likely that the perl.exe process in question is just doing some kind of file or socket I/O, and even after you call `TerminateProcess`, the OS will still wait for outstanding I/O to flush.  If you have buggy drivers in the mix, this might not ever happen. Mark Russinovich had [a blog article covering this](http://blogs.technet.com/b/markrussinovich/archive/2005/08/17/unkillable-processes.aspx) a while back, which might be useful.

Comment: @Daniel If it is doing some sort of uninterrupted I/O (say writing to disk) how do I know when it has actually finished?