# Close Notepad Window Without Saving Changes

Tags: c#, .net

I would like to close notepad file without prompting "Would you like to save changes" dialog box. I tried:

```
SendMessage(handle, 0x0010, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
```

But asks me whether I'd like to save changes or not. Also DestroyWindow(HWND) doesn't work.

How to overcome this problem?

Thanks a lot...

Comment: What are you attempting to achieve in doing this? (i.e why do you need to use notepad and not a control within your own program etc)

Comment: @Sayse It seems he's controlling a Notepad process/window from his own process.

Comment: @Mesut btw you should use constants instead of explicit values like `0x0010` if you want your question to be answered. It's too much hassle to look for what constants they actually refer to.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237628/c-sharp-process-killing just replace the process name with notepad process name

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't care about the data on notepad then simply kill its process.

```
[DllImport("user32.dll", SetLastError=true)]
static extern uint GetWindowThreadProcessId(IntPtr hWnd, out uint processId);
```

Now kill the process using its process id

```
Process p = Process.GetProcessById(processId);
p.Kill();
```

Comment: Thanks, this is actually I want.

Answer (score 0):

Just to add to the answer posted by @prem, there is absolutely no need for using APIs. .NET already includes everything to do this like in the example below.

```
var processes = Process.GetProcessesByName("notepad");
foreach (var process in processes)
    process.Kill();
```