# How do I kill the process exe with a specific location C#

Tags: c#, exe

I have a requirement of killing an exe if I find an error in the log file and restart it again. The main problem here is, I cannot just delete the exe based on the name as I have the same exe running from different folders, such as D:\A\A1.exe and D:\B\A1.exe. I only want to delete the exe from "A" folder.

I have tried to follow Dirk Vollmar's Solution (https://stackoverflow.com/a/2238316/5159431).

to this question  - [C# Process Killing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237628/c-sharp-process-killing)

But, when I debug his solution, I found that hModuleSnap Variable is invalid.

**Update - 1**

As Micky suggested, I have used Simon's Answer. It does kill the exe (Thanks for that). However, I am getting an error saying "System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception: Only part of a ReadProcessMemory or WriterocessMemory request was completed".

Here is the example code.

```
string path1 = @"F:\Software\Application\Runner.exe";


        try
        {
            Process[] runningProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();

            foreach (Process process in runningProcesses)
            {
                // now check the modules of the process
                foreach (ProcessModule module in process.Modules)
                {
                    if (module.FileName.Equals(path1))
                    {
                        process.Kill();
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Comment: Have you tried process.StartInfo?

Comment: _"System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception"_ - I ran into that when enumerating certain OS `ProcessModule`s.  You can fix it by not enumerating `process.Modules` instead reading `process.MainModule` directly.  More efficient and more importantly **no exception**.  Also you shouldn't update your question with a new question - post as a _new question_ leaving your original question unchanged :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Just use `ProcessModule.FileName` as per [Simon's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2237689/585968).  Note `FileName` returns the full path, something that is not apparent in the post.

MSDN:

> Gets the **full path** to the module.  [More...](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.processmodule.filename(v=vs.110).aspx)

OP:

> But, when I debug his solution, I found that hModuleSnap Variable is invalid.

You shouldn't require this.  Whilst [Dirk's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2238316/585968) is fine, it's rather verbose and I feel makes excessive use of native calls.

Alternatively you can use my simplified version of Simon's answer (again no native calls):

**NOTE:** You must run the following code **elevated**

```
string targetProcessPath = @"c:\windows\system32\notepad.exe";
string targetProcessName = "notepad";

Process[] runningProcesses = Process.GetProcesses();
foreach (Process process in runningProcesses)
{
    if (process.ProcessName == targetProcessName && 
        process.MainModule != null &&
        string.Compare(process.MainModule.FileName, targetProcessPath, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase)==0)
    {
        process.Kill();
    }
}
```

The above example doesn't loop around the child modules comparing paths since `Process` already has a nice `MainModule` property that we can examine.

Now the above example isn't that thrilling but it does allow you to nuke  processes called **kitty** running in various parts of your computer hard drive(s).  You might have a **c:\a\kitty.exe** and **d:\b\kitty.exe**

Comment: Thanks @MickyD. You have answered the error. Cheers

Comment: Hi @MickyD, I am getting an access denied error while running the code as a normal user. If I run as an administrator then it runs successfully. I understand the user might not have access for the system processes. I also tried to change the build platform from 32 bit to 64 bit but that hasn't helped

Comment: @RaviVyas As mentioned you must _"You must run the following code elevated"_ - in other words as an _administrator_.

Comment: Forgot to add Break;

Comment: @Tommix well no, there might be multiple instances of Notepad running